# Is there a way to use inner features of an application through Bixby?

Tags: bixby

I want Bixby to access the inner features of the application. Like to compose a message and send it in a Chat App. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can! As long as the application has REST (Or SOAP) endpoints that can be invoked, it can be called from Bixby.

Having said that, Bixby has many built-in features that allows developers to create rich, natural conversational experiences. As a general guide, the data intensive and complex computations parts of your capsule should be run on an external REST endpoint while the conversational experience (and the associated logic) should be driven from within Bixby. Hope this helps.